# Confused by use of Ruby 1.9 lambda literal in Rails ActiveRecord test suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, lambda

While trying to solve a barely-related problem, I ran across some code in this Rails ActiveRecord test file:
http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/test/models/post.rb

```
belongs_to :author_with_posts, -> { includes(:posts) }, :class_name => "Author", :foreign_key => :author_id
```

I understand (or do I?) that the **->** "arrow" creates a literal lambda, but I have no idea how or why this is a valid set of arguments for **belongs_to(name, options = {})**.  I would have expected something like this:

```
belongs_to :author_with_posts, <something that results in a key/value pair>, :class_name => "Author", :foreign_key => :author_id
```

The aforementioned file is riddled with instances of this construct and it apparently works fine, but I have no idea whatsoever why.  I tried using the -> syntax in an (apparently) similar ActiveRecord association of my own but it did not work, and I got this:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(3 for 2)
```

It seems like I am either missing something very basic?  Or perhaps there is more to the post.rb code than meets the eye?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `belongs_to` in the latest version takes 3 parameters.

The second parameter is the `scope` parameter, it has been introduced in the 4.0.0 version.

[The Code for 4.0.0 is here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1395), The commit that adds the `scope` parameter is [there](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/5a54bffe37f9e16405779d9729d7903d7c7d6c56)

It doesn't work for you because you most likely use rails 3.2.12.

Comment: D'oh!
Thanks @Intrepidd for the explanation!  You are exactly right.
I'm using Rails 3.8 but I was looking at 4.0 test code.